# Highlight other occurrences of current word in Atom

Tags: highlighting, atom-editor

I swear I had a plugin that highlighted other instances of the *current* word (i.e. the word containing or immediately preceding the caret) in the current document, but now I can't find it anywhere.

To be clear, this showed the instances of the word without having to select it first, and I found it super handy. Unfortunately packages like `highlight-selected` and `selection-highlight` don't offer any such option.